# intonation affected the meaning

Tags: intonation

Explain how the changes in intonation affect the meaning of the following sentences:

- "**My** brother bought her a red dress."
- "My **brother** bought her a red dress."
- "My brother **bought** her a red dress."
- "My brother bought **her** a red dress."
- "My brother bought her a **red** dress."

Comment: All are valid depending on context. Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: 'My brother', 'bought her a red dress', and the whole sentence may also be stressed for emphasis.

Comment: What do you suspect? Is there a particular case that you take issue with? Each emphasis emphasizes the emphasized part.

Comment: It's not just intonation; in English, it's intonation and contrastive stress, which means the boldface syllable is not only higher-pitched, but also louder.

Comment: You're not curious about "My brother bought her __a__ red dress," or "My brother bought her a red __dress__"?

Answer (score 1):

Stressing a word beyond the normal [sentence stress](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/sentence-stress.htm) of most any language means “this and not somebody/something else” and makes it topical.

> *My* brother bought her a red dress.
> It was my brother (not someone else’s) who bought her a red dress.
>
> My *brother* bought her a red dress.
> It was my brother (not someone else) who bought her a red dress.
>
> My brother *bought* her a red dress.
> My brother didn't steal, borrow, or otherwise acquire the red dress other than purchasing it.
>
> My brother bought her a *red* dress.
> My brother bought her a red dress, not some other color.

You get the idea.